# How to recover a file that was overwritten by cat?

Tags: linux, files, data-recovery

I made my files by `cat -n crib.txt`.

Then, when I did `cat > crib.txt` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, it all got overwritten.

How can I recover the overwritten file? What is the backup file restore command, if there is any, in Ubuntu Linux 20.04?

Comment: Did you actually make a backup?  If not, then your file is gone.   If you did make a backup, what did you use to make it?  `cp`? `rsync`? `tar`? something else?  Are you using a filesystem (like zfs or btrfs) that supports snapshots?  Is there a snapshot containing your over-written file?

Comment: Theoretically, if this is not an SSD, depending on the implementation the old file contents can still be on the disk, but I doubt there is a tool to recover other than identifying where the file is located on disk and using `dd`. The SSD needs to erase whole blocks or uses a different block for wear leveling, so you would not see it.

Comment: It's only useful in a small number of cases, but for "small" text files, which I have recently viewed/created, I can often reclaim some or all of it by using my terminal's backscroll buffer, and copying/pasting from there.  But as I say, this is useful in a rather range of circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

When you "delete" the file, you have not actually destroyed the contents of the file, but simply removed the file system information that points to the specific blocks of that file. It may be possible to recover contents.

Before we go any further it is important to not write anything to that partition. Unmount it! If you cannot (because it is your root, for example). Then boot from a LiveUSB, that you prepare using a different machine.

One approach would be to do it with something like `hexer`. This can work if you remember something that was in the original file. Let's say you remember that there was a phrase "Bilbo Baggins is a hobbit."

Run the following:

```
sudo hexer /dev/sda7
```

where I assume that sda7 is the partition where you had your file.

Now type: `/Bilbo Baggins is a hobbit` and press enter... and wait to see if hexer will find the data you are looking for. Once found, it's easiest to just copy what you see to a different file. To quit hexer, you do the same thing as to quit `vim`, you press [Esc] and type `:q`.

Now let's say you don't know what was in the file. There is a tool `ext4magic`. It says that it is able to recover files if the journal entry has not been lost. Give it a try as well.